# redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 32 while writing to socket. Broken pipe

Tags: redis, celery

I am running 13 celery Redis workers with a Redis broker
When I execute the python producer code on my laptop, the code executes but I frequently get this error message on the screen
I have tried to insert a sleep in the code as well and creat socket_timeout= none connection in my code but didn't help

```
Exception ignored in: <function AsyncResult.__del__ at 0x10f1694c0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cmishra/PycharmProjects/celerydockerp3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 389, in __del__
    self.backend.remove_pending_result(self)
  File "/Users/cmishra/PycharmProjects/celerydockerp3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/asynchronous.py", line 180, in remove_pending_result
    self.on_result_fulfilled(result)
  File "/Users/cmishra/PycharmProjects/celerydockerp3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/asynchronous.py", line 188, in on_result_fulfilled
    self.result_consumer.cancel_for(result.id)
  File "/Users/cmishra/PycharmProjects/celerydockerp3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 148, in cancel_for
    self._pubsub.unsubscribe(key)
  File "/Users/cmishra/PycharmProjects/celerydockerp3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 3280, in unsubscribe
    return self.execute_command('UNSUBSCRIBE', *args)
  File "/Users/cmishra/PycharmProjects/celerydockerp3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 3155, in execute_command
    self._execute(connection, connection.send_command, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cmishra/PycharmProjects/celerydockerp3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 3159, in _execute
    return command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cmishra/PycharmProjects/celerydockerp3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 686, in send_command
    self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args),
  File "/Users/cmishra/PycharmProjects/celerydockerp3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 678, in send_packed_command
    raise ConnectionError("Error %s while writing to socket. %s." %
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 32 while writing to socket. Broken pipe.
```

Comment: Yes, those are PITA... We had no other choice but to catch all those errors, and handle them in the code...